# Integrating openid authenticiation into a php application

Tags: php, authentication, openid

I want to integrate openid authentication into my php application. It must support authentication from yahoo, google, aol, msn/hotmail/live (not sure if its support openid).

I have tried searching google and have been able to come up with anything useful. I will really appreciate advises and links to good tutorials.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/php/single-sign-on-with-openid-and-google-part-1/) looks like a pretty solid tutorial covering the Google part.

Googling for ['php openid implementation tutorial'](http://www.google.nl/search?hl=ja&source=hp&q=php+openid+implementation+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) yields lots of relevant links.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Janrain Engage](https://rpxnow.com/). With the free version you can choose 6 different providers.

EDIT:

They provide an single API for authentication using OpenID and other authentication methods. Services like Twitter, Facebook and Windows Live don't use OpenID but some other method (i.e. Twitter uses something based on OAuth). Instead of implementing every method yourself you can use one single unified API.

Comment: This site is not what you think it is. It appears to be a solutions provider company. Not a openid platform. Unless I am mistaken that is.

Comment: @cdburgess: I tried to clarify what Janrain Engage (formerly rpxnow) is